# How to present correct openid-configuration when running HCP Vault behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, openid-connect, saas, hashicorp-vault

I have Vault running in Hashicorp Cloud Platform, and I'm trying to use the [OIDC provider](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/concepts/oidc-provider). Because of firewall rules and the like, I've put an Nginx reverse proxy in front of it, which is creating problems for OIDC discovery.

The openid-configuration is readable at https://my-reverse-proxy.example.com/v1/admin/identity/oidc/provider/my-provider/.well-known/openid-configuration. But the endpoints inside that file are all to the cluster itself:

```
{
  "issuer": "https://my-vault-cluster.hashicorp.cloud:8200/v1/admin/identity/oidc/provider/my-provider",
  "jwks_uri": "https://my-vault-cluster.hashicorp.cloud:8200/v1/admin/identity/oidc/provider/my-provider/.well-known/keys",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://my-vault-cluster.hashicorp.cloud:8200/ui/vault/admin/identity/oidc/provider/my-provider/authorize",
  "token_endpoint": "https://my-vault-cluster.hashicorp.cloud:8200/v1/admin/identity/oidc/provider/my-provider/token",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "https://my-vault-cluster.hashicorp.cloud:8200/v1/admin/identity/oidc/provider/my-provider/userinfo",
  ...
}
```

How can I fix this? Do I need to set some headers in Nginx? Or is there some config I can do in Vault? Note that this is HCP, so I don't have full control of [Vault Configuration](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is pretty standard in nginx, all I needed to do was add this to the location block:

```
sub_filter_types application/json;
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter "https://my-vault-cluster.hashicorp.cloud:8200" "https://my-reverse-proxy.example.com";
```